# Algorithm for modular function performing different operations?

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization

Sometimes I come across situations where I need to execute a set of code multiple times but with slight modifications. Consider 2 following cases:

```
Case 1:
A
B
C

Case 2:
A
D
C

//A, B, C, D are used to represent a set of code lines
```

Now there is no similarity between the lines of code in `B` & `D` so I am creating 2 different functions currently in my application.
However the size of code in `B` or `D` is very small in comparison to `A` or `C`.
I cannot create separate functions just for `A` & `C` because they use some common variables and it would be very messy to pass these variables as arguments.

So it looks like there is only a single solution to my problem.
Combine both the cases into a single function and choose between one of these cases by passing a `bool` as argument to this function. This however results in a very large size function to maintain.
So I am looking for some better alternatives as I am sure many people must have come across such situations.

**EDIT:**
consider just for the sake of simplicity a string variable `myString`.

```
A intialises it with some value.

B/D modify it according to some conditions.

C uses myString for some purpose, say write to file.
```

All in all there is flow of data like this:

```
Case 1:
A -> B -> C

Case 2:
A -> D -> C
```

Just that there is flow of a lot of data to separate each of these sets to different functions.

Comment: Would it be possible to define a single abstract function signature that would work for both B and D? You could then pass a function pointer to execute the middle part.

Comment: "I cannot create separate functions just for A & C because they use some common variables and it would be very messy to pass these variables as arguments." - I'm sorry bot that's how refactoring works. It's sometimes hard. And you can't really avoid it.

Comment: @H2CO3 - OP said that A and C share common variables; I was asking about B and D. Perhaps OP meant that A and C share too much with B and D, but that's not what was said.

Comment: @TedHopp can you please show by code what you mean by "to define a single abstract function signature that would work for both B and D"?

Comment: @TedHopp yes A and C share variables with B/D. That is why B/D are between A and C.

Comment: This almost seems like a call for the Strategy / Policy design pattern.  ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options I can think of:

- Create a class with A, B, C and D as functions.

  All the common variables can be member variables of this class.
- Create a class that simply stores all the common variables.

  This can be passed by reference to A, B, C and D (so you would just pass a single variable).
- Consider trying to refactor them so you minimize the number of common variables they use.

  This can be done in addition to either of the above, or by itself.

  Without knowing what exactly you are doing, I can't really tell you whether or not this is viable, but you should keep it in mind. While the above-mentioned parameter class is just a single variable, it's essentially just a wrapper for a bunch of variables - one should still attempt to minimize the amount of them.

Comment: your solution would be acceptable if there were large number of calls to the same class object. But in my case if I create the class then there would be only 2 calls to the object. Seems very little to create a new class to run some code. But as you said you cannot give specific solution until seeing the code. So thanks for providing a viable solution.

Comment: @Cool_Coder if A and C are really as big as you make them sound, I think putting this all into a class is not at all a bad idea.  Don't get stuck in the frame of mind that a class has to be an "object" or whatever: if the code is cleaner, simpler, faster that way, just do it that way... I envision something like, the class has a `populate` function that sets all of the data, etc. that gets passed to A, and has `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` functions that get called in the natural way.

Comment: @Cool_Coder and to be honest, the way this would probably get solved in plain C is that a `struct` would get created that holds the data common to the functions, and a pointer to it would get passed around.  You could take this approach as well.  However, having a monster-sized function seems like probably the worst of all approaches.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you can do is define B and D as functor classes:

```
// this is a functor
struct B_add {
  B_add(int x) : x_(x) {}
  int operator()(int y) { return x_ + y; }
  void set_x(int x) { x_ = x; }

private:
  int x_;
};

struct D_mult {
  D_mult(int x) : x_(x) {}
  int operator()(int y) { return x_ * y; }
  void set_x(int x) { x_ = x; }

private:
  int x_;
};
```

Then inside the `long_function_that_takes_either_B_or_D`

```
template <typename F> 
void long_function_that_takes_either_B_or_D(F & f) 
{
    A...

    f.set_x(result_of_a);
    int result_for_c = f(); //B or D

    C...
}
```

Main:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    long_function_that_takes_either_B_or_D(B_add(42));
    long_function_that_takes_either_B_or_D(D_mult(24));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It brakes OO design but i think you can try to arrange it into one class

```
#include <stdio.h>

class SimpleClass
{
    public:
    SimpleClass(void){}
    void someFunction(void (* zprintf)(const char *) ) //zprintf is pointer to  B or D functionality
    {
        printf("calling zprintf function\n"); //This is your A code
        zprintf("hey");
        printf("called zprintf function\n"); //This is your C code
    }   
    ~SimpleClass(void)
     {}
};
```

And then use it like this :

```
void zprintf1(const char * str )
{
    printf("i'm printing %s\n", str);
}


void zprintf2(const char * str )
{
   printf("I don't want to print %s\n", str);
}
```

.
.
.

```
SimpleClass simpleClass;
simpleClass.someFunction(zprintf1);
simpleClass.someFunction(zprintf2);
```

It is a hack i know, but you can make it more pretty.

Answer (score -1):

Use defines to generate code.

```
// A
if (runB)
    // B
else 
    // D
// C
```

Comment: I dont understand how this answers my question.

Comment: I edited according to your problem change, hope you get it now

Comment: "So it looks like there is only a single solution to my problem. Combine both the cases into a single function and choose between one of these cases by passing a bool as argument to this function. This however results in a very large size function to maintain. So I am looking for some better alternatives as I am sure many people must have come across such situations." What you are suggesting is already what I have mentioned in the question.

Comment: Tell me why then is that the above(edited) solution doesn't cut it?

Comment: Because if A, B, C, D are all in one function then the size of the functions is too large to maintain easily. Also this is against the modularity principle.